# Trying to add a column to a stored procedure, receiving bound error with union

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to add a column to a stored procedure.

The query uses a `UNION` and I am receiving this error message:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure uspCrystalSTUWEFRPT, Line 26
>   The multi-part identifier "vStudentsAll.StudentLeavingDestination"
>   could not be bound.

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspCrystalSTUWEFRPT]
   @Year int
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT
       studentYears.ID, vStudentsAll.StudentLeavingDestination, 
       vStudentsAll.studentNameInternal as nameInternal, 
       vStudentsAll.StudentYearLevel as YearLevel, 
       vStudentsAll.StudentYearLevelSort as YearLevelSort, 
       studentYears.StudentCampus, studentYearsHistory.modifiedDate, 
       studentYears.leavingDate, studentYears.returningDate, 
       luStudentLeavingReason.Description as leavingReason
   FROM
       studentYearsHistory 
   LEFT JOIN
       studentYears ON studentYearsHistory.ID = studentYears.ID
                    AND studentYearsHistory.fileYear = studentYears.fileYear
   LEFT JOIN 
       luStudentLeavingReason ON studentYears.leavingReason = luStudentLeavingReason.Code 
   LEFT JOIN 
       vStudentsAll ON studentYears.ID = vStudentsAll.ID 
                    AND vStudentsAll.currentSemesterOnlyFlag = 1
   WHERE
       YEAR(studentYears.leavingDate) = @Year
       AND studentYears.status <> 'LOA'
       AND seq IN (SELECT MIN(seq) FROM studentYearsHistory
                   WHERE YEAR(studentYearsHistory.leavingDate) = @Year
                     AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM studentYears
                                WHERE YEAR(studentYears.leavingDate) = @Year)
                   GROUP BY studentYearsHistory.ID)

    UNION

    SELECT
        pastStudents.ID, 
        vStudentsAll.StudentLeavingDestination,
        community.nameInternal,
        pastStudents.LastYearLevel,
        CASE pastStudents.LastYearLevel 
           WHEN '0' THEN '100'
           WHEN '1' THEN '101'
           WHEN '2' THEN '102'
           WHEN '3' THEN '103'
           WHEN '4' THEN '104'
           WHEN '5' THEN '105'
           WHEN '6' THEN '106'
           WHEN '7' THEN '107'
           WHEN '8' THEN '108'
           WHEN '9' THEN '109'
           WHEN '10' THEN '110'
           WHEN '11' THEN '111'
           WHEN '12' THEN '112'
           ELSE pastStudents.LastYearLevel 
        END AS YearLevelSort,
        pastStudents.LastCampus,
        studentYearsHistory.modifiedDate,
        pastStudents.LeftDate, 
        NULL,
        luStudentLeavingReason.Description as leavingReason
    FROM 
        pastStudents 
    LEFT JOIN
        studentYearsHistory ON studentYearsHistory.ID = pastStudents.ID 
    LEFT JOIN
        luStudentLeavingReason ON pastStudents.leavingReason = luStudentLeavingReason.Code 
    LEFT JOIN
        community ON pastStudents.ID = community.ID
    WHERE
        YEAR(pastStudents.LeftDate) = @Year
        AND seq IN (SELECT MIN(seq) FROM studentYearsHistory
                    WHERE YEAR(studentYearsHistory.leavingDate) = @Year
                      AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM pastStudents
                                 WHERE YEAR(pastStudents.leftDate) = @Year)
                    GROUP BY studentYearsHistory.ID)
```

Comment: The error is from the second `SELECT` query in the `UNION`. The table `vStudentsAll` is not part of it

Comment: A word of advice: use a meaningful alias for your tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `UNION`.

In Your first `SELECT` query in `UNION`, you are joining `vStudentsAll` table with `LEFT JOIN`. But your second `SELECT` query doesn't have reference to that table.